# Header not aligning to the center

Tags: html, css, responsive

I have a text in the header that I would like to center on smaller screens but I have tried various options and it's not working. Could someone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance for your help.

Edit: added more code. If I add "width:70%" to .name, it aligns it to the center on some iphones but not others.

[image: Text not aligning to the center]

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #e9e9f3;
}

/* Header */
.header .name {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.5em;
  left: 1em;
  margin-left: 4%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-family: 'Archivo', sans-serif;
}

.social-icon-header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3em;
  right: 2em;
  height: auto;
}

/* Tablets and under */
@media (max-width: 768px) {
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Header */

.social-icon-header {
  display: none;
}

.name {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center !important;
  justify-content: center !important;
  width: 70%;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero">
  <!--Header-->
  <div class="header">
    <h2 class="name">Name</h2>
    <a class="social-icon-header" href="https://www.tiktok.com" target="_blank">
      <i class="fab fa-tiktok fa-2x"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Check to see if your `div` and `h2` elements are the full width of the viewable screen. If not, it's likely centering on the width it's covering, rather than the screen width.

Comment: on your css change `.name` to `.header`

Comment: the code you've included works as expected, so your issue is going to be further up the element hierarchy

Comment: Perhaps add more code so the issue can be reproduced

Comment: @tretuser can you share more css?

Comment: Added more code. Thanks in advance for all your help!

Comment: @tretuser I am assuming you just want the name to be centered based on the image and the image is in `.header`. With that assumption and your current code in the question - set `.header` to position relative, set `.name` to width 100% remove display flex and justify-content from `.name` it's not needed, remove !important from text-align center, should not be needed

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `width: 100%` to the `name` class, so it would take 100% width of the parent container.

```css
.name {
  text-align: center !important;
  justify-content: center !important;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Why is flex needed at all?

Comment: You are totally right, it's not needed. I just copied it from question and added `width: 100%`. Let me update the answer.

Comment: The h2 is a block element as far as the code goes, width is already 100%, justify-content is also not needed since it is no longer flex. Something else is causing the issue

Comment: I tried adding "width: 100%" but it didn't move the 'name' text at all. Making width: 70% moved the name text to the center on some screen resolutions but not others. I have no idea what could be causing this. Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the positioning of `.name` in the media query and set `text-align: center` for `.header`. In this way you can change the whole layout for screens with a different size (like in your example a maximum of 768px).
Just make sure that you reset other values that you set before (outside the media query, like `top`, `left` and `margin-left` for `.name`) that you don't need for other screen sizes. You also forgot to close media query tag.

Also beware of the fact that it's good practice to design css mobile first and then use media queries for bigger screens. https://www.browserstack.com/guide/how-to-implement-mobile-first-design

If you replace you css with the following it'll work:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #e9e9f3;
}

/* Header */
.header .name {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.5em;
  left: 1em;
  margin-left: 4%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-family: 'Archivo', sans-serif;
}

.social-icon-header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3em;
  right: 2em;
  height: auto;
}

 /* Tablets and under */
@media (max-width: 768px) {

  .social-icon-header {
      display: none;
  }
  
  .header {
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  .header .name {
    position: relative;
    left: auto;
    top: auto;
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```